# Getting previous entry values as rows in current entry by userid in mysql

Tags: mysql, lag, partition

I am trying to create MySQL dataset which has entries from previous study (surgical study with the first study having value of 1) as well for that userid. Each user can have multiple studies. I am trying to use Lag function to get previous study data. I am getting duplicate values for study 1 while trying to use the lag function.

```
WITH Complete_Data AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Data
    GROUP BY UserId, studyno
)
SELECT *, LAG(indication_of_failure, 1)
OVER (
        PARTITION BY UserId
        ORDER BY studyno
    ) prev_study_indication_of_failure
    , 
    LAG(BCVA_State,1)
    OVER (
        PARTITION BY UserId
        ORDER BY studyno
    ) prev_study_BCVA
FROM 
    Complete_Data
    GROUP BY UserId, studyno
    ;
```

I am expecting nulls in prev_study_indication_of_failure and prev_study_BCVA when studyno = 1 but filled with values when studyno >=2.

Due to duplicate entries for studyno = 1, I am getting values in prev_study_indication_of_failure and prev_study_BCVA

---

**Sample Data**

### [image: The following image gives the actual data sample]

**Expected outcome**
[image: The following image gives the expected outcome]

Comment: Why do you have `GROUP BY` in your queries? You're not doing any aggregation.

Comment: I added group by thinking that it will solve my problem but despite that, the outcome remained the same

Comment: Could your provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I have added the sample data and expected result to the question above